# Send SMS with Python without any Phone Number or API

Tags: python, sms

I want to send SMS Messages to anyone without having a phone number or any 3rd party API.
How can I do this? Is there any way of such kind? Is this Possible using Python Programming Language?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send SMS without using any external API.

Comment: Nooooo.Oh really !